# Why Mouse events does not work on full screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

If I do:

stage.displayState =StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE

the projector will go full screen, but no mouse events work, any idea how solve this?

**EDIT**

Here is my implementation:

```
stage.displayState =StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
stage.mouseLock = true;
```

the problem happens only when create a project in windows, no mouse events work..

*EDIT2*

```
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED, fullscreenHandler);
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullscreenHandler);

stage.displayState =StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

// BUT THIS HANDLER IS NOT CALLED  
function fullscreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void {

  if(event.type == FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED) {
     stage.mouseLock = true; 
  }
}
```

EDIT 3:

if I check for event `FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN` and try to set `stage.mouseLock = true;`

```
if(event.type == FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN) {
     stage.mouseLock = true; 
  }
```

I get this error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #3707: Property can not be set in non full screen mode
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `stage.mouseLock` to `true` after you have entered fullscreen?

Comment: Shouldn't your wait for the `FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPT` is triggered before setting `stage.mouseLock = true;`?

Comment: but, how to detect the event?

Comment: Instead of editing your question you should add the relevant code. It's hard to say what may be wrong with out looking at the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `mouseLock` property of stage to `true` when your application has entered fullscreen:

```
public function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void {
  if(event.type == FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED) {
     stage.mouseLock = true; 
  }
}
```

You add the above event handler like:

```
// will be fired when the user clicks the 'allow' button for fullscreen interactive
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED, fullscreenHandler);
// will be fired when enter/exit fullscreen
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullscreenHandler);
```

To be able to work in fullscreen mode you also must add the following parameter to your embed code:

```
<object>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
  <embed src="example.swf" allowfullscreen="true" /> 
</object>
```

Comment: please see EDIT2, the handler is not called

Comment: for some reason, the handler is getting called now, but I get this error:[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #3707: Property can not be set in non full screen mode.

Comment: Which version of Flash Player are you using? It seems to be a bug in version 11.3 that you can solve by modifying your `fullScreen` event handler. Check this link: https://github.com/renaun/ActionScriptExamples/blob/master/FullscreenInteractiveMouseLock/src/FullscreenInteractiveMouseLock.as

Comment: thanks for the link, it worked! but, I had to switch fullscreenTakeOver to false for all FLV playback components :(